# 100% uptime for web application

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat, high-availability

Our requirement from our next web app is that we will be able to deploy a new version of the web app without a downtime.

how is it possible to achieve such task?

does it mean we need to run 2 different servers (tomcats) ? and redirect users to each one when needed?

are there tools that are doing this specific task? in what category these tools in?

Thanks

Comment: You should search for load balancers in order to have 2 different tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Tomcat's [parallel deployment](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment) feature. It is available from Tomcat 7 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget, 100% availability is impossible - it may happen for a certain period, but no one can guarantee it, no matter what setup you have.

But since you're looking for a smooth change from one version to another, then the best you can do is update one node and switch nodes then. Of course, since you likely have sessions which shouldn't disconnected, you'll need to make sure that an instance (e.g. load balancer) directs all new requests to the new node, whereas old session requests stay on the old node until no one uses it anymore, after which you can upgrade the second node and finally, balance load again to both nodes.